# HTTP Preview at localhost [Stopped, Syncronized]

Tags: eclipse, http, server, bundle

I'm new to programming and I'm currently facing this problem. 
[[I leave here some pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhJzh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G35lr.png)

I tried downloading some files that I find on Internet searching the problem but it remained the same. 
[This are the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93PRc.png) 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There's a strange dependency problem happening as the platform moves to packaging SLF4J directly from Maven and recommended everyone else not require the bundle be present in their own features, resulting in some installations not having it when they should. Don't worry if that doesn't explain anything to you, a possible workaround is to manually install the bundle using the CLI, after exiting the IDE:
`eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest -installIU org.slf4j.api`